# How to rotate text in one line with html and bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I would like to rotate some text in the first row. What's happened is that the results display the text in 2 lines, when I would like to get it in one. What should I add?

Many Thanks

```css
p {

width: auto;

height: auto;


/* Rotate div */

-ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */

-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

transform: rotate(270deg);

}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered primary-color white-text">
                <thead >
                    <tr>
                        <th height="200" style="width: 390px;">Point Description</th>   
                        <th><p>Controller Address</p></th>
                        <th><p>Module Address</p></th>
                        <th><p>Point Address</p></th>                    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
              
            </table>
```

[image: html]

[image]

Comment: Where is that text? It's not in your table. Please post your full HTML code (at least the entire relevant part)

Comment: Just added Point description, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy - just add classes and non-breaking spaces:

```
<th height="200" style="width: 390px;" class="rotated">Point Description</th>   
<th class="rotated"><p>Controller&nbsp;Address</p></th>
<th class="rotated"><p>Module&nbsp;Address</p></th>
<th class="rotated"><p>Point&nbsp;Address</p></th>
```

And in CSS:

```
.rotated {
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to do this already. The issue that I've got is that the next is displayed in 2 lines instead one. I would like to get address above controller.

Comment: @Arielis Edited question, any better?

Comment: non breaking spaces was the answer. Any idea, why setting up the width does not work (as shown on the updated picture). Thanks